# Pass route via query string in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

Using angular interceptors and route-ui I am capturing a `401 Unauthorized` request and redirecting to a login url.

I want to send the state the user was previously in on the query string to redirect after successful login but I can't find the actual url with parameters included in the `$state` service.

This is what i have but `$state.current.url` does not include the parameters of the state.

```
$state.go('home.login', {next: $state.current.url});
//$state.current.url = /user/{id}
//$state.params      = {id:5}
```

I would like the url to be something like:

```
http://example.com/login?next=/user/5
```

And after a successful login the user would be redirected to `http://example.com/user/5`

Is there any way i can get the `/user/5` url from the `$state` service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `$location`service:

```
$location.path()
```

check more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)